# Rails 4 - SimpleForm associations not creating records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, simple-form, simple-form-for

app/models/encounter.rb

```
class Encounter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: orders
end
```

app/models/order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :encounter
  has_many :order_tests
  has_many :tests, through :order_tests
end
```

app/models/order_test.rb

```
Class OrderTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :test
end
```

app/models/test.rb

```
Class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_tests
  has_many :orders, through: :order_tests
end
```

I am trying to add multiple tests to the **first** order of a given encounter. I am trying to achieve that through the use of simple_form associations. Here is my setup in the view

```
= simple_form_for @encounter do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.patient_id
  = f.doctor_id
  = simple_form_for @encounter.orders.first do |o|
    = o.associations tests, as: :check_boxes, collection: Test.all
```

this is my server log

```
Started PATCH "/encounters/71?next_step=Meds+Entry&step_group=accessioning&task=326" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-05 13:10:50 -0500
Processing by EncountersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qSC7IHInq0fqArDXsXbKENSMYM/5B1Ijry4hZ1o6oVtyVb14ECnt95rNX2Pqv+GHmanugkBvQfc686JmKJeSeA==", "encounter"=>{"patient_id"=>"", "organization_id"=>"", "address_id"=>"", "name"=>"", "encounter_type_id"=>"3", "encounter_at"=>"", "do_next_step"=>"0"}, "patient_first_name"=>"", "patient_middle_name"=>"", "patient_last_name"=>"", "patient_dob"=>"", "patient_gender"=>"", "patient_race"=>"", "patient_ssn"=>"", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "zip"=>"", "npi"=>"", "order"=>{"test_ids"=>["1", "2", "3", ""]}, "button"=>"", "next_step"=>"Meds Entry", "step_group"=>"accessioning", "task"=>"326", "id"=>"71"}
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "encounters".* FROM "encounters" WHERE "encounters"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "71"]]
  Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "tasks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 326]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3002/encounters/71
Completed 302 Found in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)
```

It seems as if it fails to add any records, I'm a little unsure of how to go about this. I am trying to add a new record in the **order_tests** table (order_id, test_id) for every checkbox that's checked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the log clipping is for updating an encounter, there is an obvious problem in that there is no update command being called... random example from a project I'm working on:

```
  SQL (22.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "trust_name" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["trust_name", "ttrusdt dfsdf"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-05 19:03:26.823849"], ["id", 24]]
```

This leads me to believe that there is something unexpected happening in the controller action... it may be helpful to post your code for it.

If it were failing elsewhere, like a validation, I would expect to see the update command in the log followed by a rollback... rejecting the update.